# how to replace emoji codes like :) in python

Tags: python, emoji

i want to replace all the emoji characters codes. I have tried `emojis` library

```
def give_emoji_free_text(text):
    return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(r'', text)
```

but this removes the actual emojis.

Got a script that replaces the emojis like :) but if this is a word

```
import csv
import re



def translate(user_string, abbreviation_mapping_file_path="./file.txt"):
    user_string = user_string.split(" ")
    j = 0
    for _str in user_string:
        # File Access mode [Read Mode]
        accessMode = "r"
        with open(abbreviation_mapping_file_path, accessMode) as myCSVfile:
            # Reading file as CSV with delimiter as "=", so that abbreviation are stored in row[0] and phrases in row[1]
            dataFromFile = csv.reader(myCSVfile, delimiter="=")
            # Removing Special Characters.
            # _str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]', '', _str)
            for row in dataFromFile:
                # Check if selected word matches short forms[LHS] in text file.
                # print(_str)
                if _str.upper() == row[0].upper():
                    # If match found replace it with its appropriate phrase in text file.
                    user_string[j] = row[1].strip()
            myCSVfile.close()
        j = j + 1
    # Replacing commas with spaces for final output.
    return ' '.join(user_string)
```

and the txt file contains

```
:)=
:D=
```

this works if text is like `my emoji :)` but if the text is like `my emoji:)` it skips.

is there any way to remove all the emoji codes

Comment: `return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(r'', text)` you're replacing it with Empty string, that's why. the first parameter of `sub` is what to replace with.

Comment: @thethiny i want to replace with the empty string.. but this does not work on :) ,  ;), :P

Comment: try simple regex expressions. make a list of emojis you want to remove, call it emoji_list for example. Then: `for emoji in emoji_list: sentence = re.sub(re.escape(emoji), '', sentence)`

Comment: it worked but there is space i just want to remove the emoji

Comment: remove the space from the 2nd parameter of re.sub

Comment: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: You didn't get me. I meant use `''` instead of `' '` this way it won't be replaced with a space.

Comment: oh sorry, actually in sentence itself there are two space.. 'my :) sentence'

Comment: then you need to first `re.sub('[ ]+', ' ', sentence)` to get rid of duplicate spaces.